# Conservation of crystal momentum in a collision of two transverse acoustic phonons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics

Okay, so I have the follow question. I have been bugging my professor for an answer, but his answer confuses me.

Say we have a 1D phonon collision process where two transverse acoustic phonons combine to give one longitudinal acoustic phonon. They have dispersion relations

$$\omega_{TA}=\omega_0\left\lvert\sin\frac{ka}{2}\right\rvert$$

and

$$\omega_{LA}=2\omega_0\left\lvert\sin\frac{ka}{2}\right\rvert$$

For which of the following acoustic wave vectors $k_1$ and $k_2$ is the process allowed

$k_1=k_2=\frac{2\pi}{5a}$ or $k_1=k_2=\frac{2\pi}{3a}$ or $k_1=-k_2=\frac{\pi}{a}$ or $k_1=k_2=\frac{\pi}{a}$ or $k_1=-k_2=\frac{2\pi}{3a}$

My first thought process was to look at the conservation of the crystal momentum

$$\sum_{i} \hbar\textbf{k}_i=\sum_{j}\hbar\textbf{k}_j$$

And then upon asking the professor he gave a somewhat handwavy explanation about adding up the two vectors and subtracting the Fourier transform resulting in some vector $-2\pi/a$ and it just confused me even more. How would I go about solving this?

Any tips would be hugely helpful.

Comment: Crystal momentum is only conserved up to multiples of the reciprocal lattice vector $G=2\pi /a$. That is likely what your professor was telling you.